# Is there a replacement for Bumblebee yet?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

[Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee) used to be a package that allowed you to start specific programs with dedicated graphics without having to reboot your system to choose if you wanted to use integrated or dedicated.

Unfortunately it seems like it's been completely discontinued and not updated for 7 years or so.

This is a really useful feature so I was wondering if there was anything similar I could use today?